# Want to keep "ALL" option in Javascript-CSS filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are about 16 posts in the front page and there is a filter with 4 drop-downs showing post categories. I have added category names as classes to the post div and I'm hiding them with javascript.

Used the following code to filter posts.

```
$('#filter select').change(function () {
var upper = $('#upper').val(); //these are IDs of select.
var sole = $('#sole').val();
var toe = $('#toe').val();
var midsole = $('#midsole').val();



var classes = '.' + [upper, sole, toe, midsole].join('.');
$('.box').hide().filter(classes,toeall).show(); 
});
```

.box is the class of the post container. this works perfectly.

The first option in each dropdown is "ALL" and I want to make it work.

For example, if I select ALL in "TOE" dropdown, it has to keep the existing results and and also show those posts which has one of the TOE categories as class.

Using the following code I tried to find all the values of TOE dropdown and show the posts with those classes too.

```
var toeall = new Array(); 
$('#toe option').each(function() {
   toeall.push('.'+$(this).val());
});

if(toe=="all")
{
    $('.box').hide().filter(classes&&toeall).show();
}
```

I know the code above is incorrect but can someone explain how to do it?

UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/kd3ybnnx/1/ <- Demo after answer from madalin ivascu

Comment: Could you please include the relevant html in your question? The Fiddle is a bonus, but we should be able to reproduce your problem/scenario from information present in the question itself without having to look elsewhere.

Comment: @DavidThomas I have cleaned up the demo. HTML is way too long man!!

Comment: Check out my answer, it also includes an alert which states the classes searched for. You can easily see the 'all' options are filtered out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $('#filter select').change(function () {
var upper = $('#upper').val(); //these are IDs of select.
var sole = $('#sole').val();
var toe = $('#toe').val();
var midsole = $('#midsole').val(),

array1 = [upper, sole, toe, midsole];
        var ar =[];
            $.each(array1,function(index,val){
              if (val != 'all') {//note the value of all option has to be all
                  ar.push(val);
               }

            });
        if(ar.length == 0) {$('.box').show();} else {
           var classes = '.' + ar.join('.');
            $('.box').hide().filter(classes).show(); 
        }       

});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kd3ybnnx/4/

Comment: Please see this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kd3ybnnx/

If you change an option to something else and select ALL again, it won't work!

Comment: this has done something! but I will need some time to make sure that it's working perfectly. Will accept if it does. thank dude!

Answer (score 0):

Well.. you can try this:

```
$('#filter select').change(function () {
    var upper = $('#upper').val(); //these are IDs of select.
    var sole = $('#sole').val();
    var toe = $('#toe').val();
    var midsole = $('#midsole').val(),
    array = [upper, sole, toe, midsole];
    var counter = 0;
    $.each(array,function(index,val){
         if (val == 'all') {//note the value of all option has to be all
             counter++;
         }
    })
    if(counter == array.length) {
        $('.box').show();
    } else {
        var classes = '.' + array.join('.');
        $('.box').hide().filter(classes).show(); 
    }
});
```

Basicaly, I check if all the selects have `all`, if they do I show all boxes. Else I filter because there is 1 filter at least.

Comment: This doesn't work as it selects '.all' elements. Since they don't exist no elements show up.

Comment: Where is it selecting the all elements ? `all` is an option.

Comment: @JoelAlmeida Thanks man! this has helped too. and guys stay cool :)

Comment: `all` is an option but it is not a class of the filterable divs. They have classes like `box cat-30 cat-37 cat-23 cat-26`. If you would select for `.all.cat-23` it would return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to select values that are not 'all'. The way you would do this is walk through all elements and remove the ones you don't need from the array. Normally you would for example do this with an `array.splice(index, 1)` function

The problem (from a previous answer) with `splice` however is that it removes indices from the array so if there are four elements, the third is removed and when the `each loop` enters the fourth element there is no fourth element because it became the third. To solve this you can either:

1. Put the required elements in a **new** array instead of removing them
   from the **old** array
2. Use an array where index doesn't change value (make it associative)
3. Use an each loop with an i variable that decreases every time you delete an element

UPDATE:

4. use a native javascript filter to easily filter out stuff

<strike>I've used the first from the list to create this example that works (tested it):</strike> I've chosen the fourth technique since it's mostly vanilla javascript, check out the commented code and the chosen alternative:

http://codepen.io/xaddict/pen/PqqYBa?editors=001

It's the easiest solution out of the <strike>three</strike> four above and remains readable

It uses a filter option to easily remove the 'all' values

```
function isNotAll(value) {
  return value != 'all';
}
totals.filter(isNotAll);
```

Complete code:

```js
$('#filter select').change(function() {
  var upper = $('#upper').val(),
      sole = $('#sole').val(),
      toe = $('#toe').val(),
      midsole = $('#midsole').val(),
      totals = [upper, sole, toe, midsole];
  function isNotAll(value) {
    return value != 'all';
  }
  var filtered = totals.filter(isNotAll);
  $(".box").show();
  if (filtered.length) {
    $(".box").hide().filter('.'+filtered.join('.')).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: was about to use recursion :)

Comment: Filter works even better. I forgot about it the first time around :P